# How to make the pdf reader show more good appearance?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, fonts

A simple sentence in a pdf book shown with Okular.

[image]

Shown with Document Viewer.

[image]

Shown with chrome browser.

[image]

Why the character's width between `C` and `r` ,and `T` and `h` are shown so widely in Okular and Document Viewer than in chrome browser?
How to make the pdf reader(Okular and Document Viewer) show more good appearance ?
Here is my sample pdf file in dropbox.

[sample pdf-just for testing](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xx6mr6grp6h2zvd/theory.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Either the font itself or your typesetting software has poor or broken kerning. You need to go back to source to discover which is in error.

Comment: Do you have a link for this specific PDF?

Comment: I uploaded into my dropbox to share ,just for testing,please help me set the font and typesetting in the pdf reader.

Comment: The sample seems to have a completely different font - but the kerning is still absolutely atrocious - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIKfY.png. What are you typesetting this in & are you using good screen fonts?

Comment: Do more robust or compliant readers (Adobe Reader or Foxit or others) show the same problem? The fonts look different between the capitals and rest of the characters so it may well be that your source document is bad.

Comment: Install more fonts, specifically if you can the ones needed by  the document because it seems they are not embedded in.  In `firefox` and in `okular` the fonts are different. BTW, it is a problem of the file, enhanced from the different font substitution.

Comment: Guess confirmed, but still a guess. I opened with inkscape that page. E.g., there is a string `0 15.1861 25.17845 34.814548 46.194401`...  for the text "Keynesian Criticisms of the Theory" (tspan30) that regulates the horizontal shift. It explicitely keeps the first letter apart. Moreover, in the other part of the text that you cat from your images, you may see some _grafical_ effect on the first letter of the abstract. I think you need to install the right fonts. Or to embed them in the original document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In brief

Install the fonts required from the document or find a version with the fonts embedded.
If you cannot, you may try to enhance the rendered output installing similar fonts.

#### The story (tl;dr)

The problem you are facing, seems to arise from some missing fonts.

I open the example file with the browser (`firefox`) and with `okular`.
The shown fonts look different.

So I try with `inkscape`.
The text "Keynesian Criticisms of the Theory" (tspan30), e.g., is associated with a string for the horizontal shifts of the single characters (0 15.1861 25.17845 34.814548 46.194401).
The first letter is spaced from the others that are one close to the other. This is a desired effect.

Looking the rest of the text, and specifically the abstract you may notice an [Initial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial).
Another guess in the same direction.

Then back again to `okular`, from `File->Properties` it opens a window and from the second panel (fonts) I can read that the required fonts (JansonText-bold...) are substituded with the ones present on my system.

Under firefox they may have different substitions. So the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Determinate the font in `sample.pdf`.

```
pdffonts  sample.pdf
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
JansonText-Bold                      Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      11  0
JansonText-Roman                     Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      12  0
JansonText-Italic                    Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  no      13  0
```

Download and install `Janson Text` font in my os.
I find that such tools as `calibre`,`gv`,`okular`,`qpdfview`,`xpdf`,`document view` can't call `Janson Text` font to show the pdf file ,enve if i set  `Janson Text` font in it(for example in okular).
`Mupdf`,`foxitreader`,`adobe reader for linux version` ,`inkscape` can show text with `Janson Text` font.